# How to send email on specific date using quartz.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, quartz.net

I am creating a birthday app in asp.net mvc in which I want to send reminder email to user. I am using quartz.net for this purpose but I have no idea how to send an email on some specific date (that user will enter in the textbox)

Here is the code:

```
public static void Start()
        {
            IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<LoginController>()
             .WithIdentity("EmailReminder", "group1")
             .Build();
            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                  .WithIdentity("EmailReminder", "group1")
                  .StartAt(//how to get a value here?)
                  .WithSimpleSchedule( x => x
                       .WithIntervalInHours(1)
                      .RepeatForever())                     
                      .Build();
                      scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

I now there is a startAt() function to do the job but how can I get the value enter by the user and pass that value in startAt() function ?

Answer (score 0):

This should launch it as soon as possible:

```
   DateTime utcTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTimeKind.Utc);
   DateTimeOffset targetTime = new DateTimeOffset(utcTime);
   ...
      .StartAt(targetTime)
   ...
```

You just have to replace utcTime with the date you get from the user.